# Cannot install torch 1.6.0 on python 3.6.1 while PyPi says it is compatible

Tags: python, pip, pytorch, virtualenv

I am trying to install Torch version 1.6.0.

On the [Pypi page](https://pypi.org/project/torch/1.6.0/) it states that Torch 1.6.0 is compatible with Python >= 3.6.1.
However, the following error is thrown when trying to install Torch using pip on Python 3.6.1.

```
(.venv) python --version
>>> python 3.6.1

(.venv) pip install torch==1.6.0
>>> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch==1.6.0 (from versions: 1.7.0)
>>> ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch==1.6.0
```

I have also tried installing it on python versions 3.7.9, 3.8.0, 3.9.7, 3.10.0.

How can I resolve this issue?
If Torch 1.6.0 cannot be installed on this Python version, on which version can it be installed?

Further details:
I am using pip 22.3.1. The virtual environment is created using Visual Studio Code.

Comment: try with `python -m pip install tourch==1.6.0`

Comment: Are you by any chance using an ARM macbook?(if so, recompile everything with rosetta)

Comment: `pip install torch==1.6.0+cu101 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html`

Comment: @sahasrara62 This resulted in the same error

Comment: @ekaeo no, i am using windows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> On the Pypi page it states that Torch 1.6.0 is compatible with Python >= 3.6.1

That says nothing about OS compatibility or the availability of the correct whl files. If you check the [files tab](https://pypi.org/project/torch/1.6.0/#files)

you will see

```
torch-1.6.0-cp38-none-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl
torch-1.6.0-cp38-cp38-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
torch-1.6.0-cp37-none-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl
torch-1.6.0-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
torch-1.6.0-cp36-none-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl
torch-1.6.0-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
```

So only whl files for python 3.6 and 3.7 and only for MacOs and manylinux.

As doneforaiur has pointed out though, whl files are available from https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html

Answer (score 3):

You can install it according to [docs](https://pytorch.org/get-started/previous-versions/#v160) like this:

```
pip install torch==1.6.0+cu101 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

Choose `CUDA` version according to your `CUDA` installation.