# ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch(from versions: none)

Tags: python, pytorch, requirements.txt

I am using vscode in  mac and added torch to `requirement.txt`. when I run `pip install -r requirements.txt` it gives the error

> 'ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch (from versions: none)
> ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch'

I followed the solution in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76875782/cannot-install-torch-1-6-0-on-python-3-6-1-while-pypi-says-it-is-compatible)
instead of using requirements.txt, I opened ml.py file with interactive window and runned the code 'pip install torch==1.6.0+cu101 -f [https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html'](https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html%27)
while it solved the author's problem in the thread, I still get the same error.
How can I solve it?

> p.s I use python 3.11.5